# Restore SBS 2011 from RDX harddisk cartridge "The Parameter is Incorrect (0x80070057)"

Tags: windows, backup, image

Today i got a SBS 2011 with (malicous) encrypted files from a customer. That happens frequently. What was rare was the fact that he had a very recent backup (Windows Image Backup) on a Imation RDX Cartridge.

So i tried to do a restore with the boot-cd. After finding the Intel-Raid drivers on the internet (yes the RDX was connected to the Raid controller too) the System-Restore console found the backup and i started the restore.

After a few seconds the following message appeared: `"The Parameter is Incorrect (0x80070057)"`

I searched the internet and there was one concusion: There must be the same number of drives and enough space on the drives.

The system always had only one HDD (Raid1) and the RDX-Drive.

I removed the USB-Key before starting the restore but there was the same message.

What could prevent Windows Backup from doing this restore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: **Get rid of the RDX Drive**

1. dismounted the RDX from the server and installed it in a testing machine
2. copied the contents of the Cartridge (technically a harddisk) to another external drive.
3. Started server with boot-cd
4. loaded Raid-Driver
5. Connected external drive
6. disconnected usb-key with drivers
7. choose the system restore point
8. Restore